# Javascript object to execute delayed loops

Tags: javascript

I want to have multiple numbers on my web page "spin up" as the page loads, giving an impression like a fruit machine.

This involves a simple function with a delayed loop.  The way to do this seems to be to [use setTimeout recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop).  This works fine for just one number on the page.

However for multiple numbers spinning at the same time, each needs its own spinner object.  I used prototypes like this:

```
var Spinner = function(id){
    this.element = $('#' + id);
    this.target_value = this.element.text()
    this.initial_value = this.target_value - 30;
};

Spinner.prototype.spinUp = function() {

    loop(this.element); 

    function loop(element) {
        element.html(this.initial_value += 1);
        if (this.initial_value == this.target_value) {
                return;
            };
        clr = setTimeout(loop(element), 30);  // 30 millisecond delay
    };
};

var Spinner1 = new Spinner('number')

Spinner1.spinUp();
```

However putting a recursive function inside the prototype method causes a big crash.  Can you see a way around this?

Many thanks!

Derek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues:

- `loop()` is not how you pass a function, it's how you **invoke** a function.
- You are not calling the function as a method of the object

Try this:

```
Spinner.prototype.spinUp = function() {
    var loop = function() {
            this.element.html(this.initial_value += 1);
            if (this.initial_value == this.target_value) {
                return;
            };
            setTimeout(loop, 30); // 30 millisecond delay   
        }.bind(this); //Just flat out bind the function to this instance so we don't need to worry about it
    loop();
};
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/KAZpJ/

Answer (score 2):

When you say:

```
clr = setTimeout(loop(element), 30);
```

you are "calling" the function (then and there), and passing the value it returns as the first parameter to `setTimeout(..)`.

You would want an anonymous function doing that job:

```
setTimeout(function(){loop(element);}, 30);
```

Comment: In addition to that, the context (`this`) needs to be adjusted.